How to grab text after a special character in a join
I am doing a select query, and trying to join in another table where the common field in one table looks like "1234" and the other table has a comma and characters at the start like "BA,1234".
Table1



ID




1234


12348


505



Table2



Case_No




BA,1234


BAC,12348


FETF,505



My join will be on TableI.ID = Table2.Case_No but I only want to grab the value of the case_no column to the right of the comma (",") so that I'm joining 1234 (Table1.ID) = 1234 (Table2.Case_No)
Is this possible with a combination of charindex and right function? Haven't been able to get it to work.
Tried char index and right function but isn't working at the moment

Why not fix your design and store the value of Case_No in 2 columns?

Fixing your table design is the best thing to do, if you really want to keep going like this and get yourself deeper into troubles, show us what you have tried and where you are stuck

You can do something like: STUFF(Case_no, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Case_no), '')

right(Case_No, len(Case_no) - (charindex(',', Case_no))) seems to work for me

@siggemannen. Your solution also worked out great. Will look into STUFF function more.

You could join on the following logic:
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.Case_No LIKE '%,' + t1.ID;

But a better long term design approach would be to store the two CSV components of the Case_No in separate columns.
